# Calculating Dynamic Critical Exponent in Continuum Field Theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, critical-phenomena

For a critical point controlled by $\delta$ described by a correlation length $\xi$ and a correlation time $\xi_\tau$, the critical exponent $\nu$ and the dynamic critical exponent $z$ is defined as $\xi\sim|\delta|^\nu$ and $\xi_\tau\sim\xi^z$.

Now, for consider a generic continuum field theory describing some critical exponent. For example, consider the relativistic $\phi^4$ theory
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = |\partial_\mu \phi|^2 + m^2|\phi|^2 + g|\phi|^4
\end{equation}
I know that one can calculate $\nu$ in this theory by calculating the the anomalous dimension of $|\phi|^2$. How would one go about calculating $z$ in this theory? How about for generic continuum field theories?

Answer (score 1):

Generally one expects $z \neq 1$ only in the absence of Lorentz invariance of the bare theory. As written, the theory is Lorentz invariant.  So $z$ is protected against renormalizations. Perhaps if you couple the boson with some other degrees of freedom, whose dynamics lacks Lorentz symmetry, a $z \neq 1$ may be possible.

Comment: Right, I understand that this is the general idea, but in terms of a concrete calculation/proof, how does one go about showing this?

Comment: If you're looking for the latter way to generate $z\neq 1$ behavior, quantum critical metals are the place to look up: (examples)
[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08172
[2] https://www.condmatjclub.org/uploads/2014/07/JCCM_JULY_2014_01.pdf